# Apply less function to element selectors following the function output

Tags: css, less

I have less code which looks as follows:

```
.my-func(@color) {
  &:not(:hover) {
    color: @color;
  }
}
.class1, .class2 {
  .subClass1 {
    .my-func("#ffffff");
  }
}
```

This results in the following css:

```
.class1 .subClass1:not(:hover),
.class2 .subClass1:not(:hover) {
  color: "#ffffff";
}
```

What I want to do is to generate css that, in addition to outputting what is being output right now, will also allow me to add more selectors after the part of the css that is output by the function.

So I want css that looks like this (I added the line breaks):

```
.class1 .subClass1:not(:hover),
.class2 .subClass1:not(:hover),

.class1 .subClass1:not(:hover) p.some-other-class,
.class2 .subClass1:not(:hover) p.some-other-class,

.class1 .subClass1:not(:hover) p.yet-another-class,
.class2 .subClass1:not(:hover) p.yet-another-class {
  color: "#ffffff";
}
```

So can this be done using less features, so that I can somehow pass in a list of two element selectors to the function (`p.some-other-class` and `p.yet-another-class`), and the function will run for  (to give the first two rows of output) and will then run for the elements in the list passed in to append these *after* the output of the function? Something like running an `.each` function on the list passed in, within the function, to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
@class: some-other-class, yet-other-class;

.my-func(@color) {
  &:not(:hover)  {
      color: @color;
  }
  each(@class, {
    &:not(:hover) p.@{value} {
      color: @color;
    }
  })

}
.class1, .class2 {
  .subClass1 {
    .my-func(#ffffff);
  }
}
```

---

If you want to pass the list to the function adjust like below:

```css
.my-func(@color,@list) {
  &:not(:hover)  {
      color: @color;
  }
  each(@list, {
    &:not(:hover) p.@{value} {
      color: @color;
    }
  })

}

@class: some-other-class, yet-other-class;
.class1, .class2 {
  .subClass1 {
    .my-func(#ffffff,@class);
  }
}
```

---

More generic with any kind of selector like below:

```
.my-func(@color,@list) {
  &:not(:hover)  {
      color: @color;
  }
  each(@list, {
    &:not(:hover) @{value} {
      color: @color;
    }
  })

}

@class: ~"p.some-other-class", ~"div.yet-other-class";
.class1, .class2 {
  .subClass1 {
    .my-func(#ffffff,@class);
  }
}
```